# How to use value that a function reurned?

Tags: php, oop, return-value

I want to use `$bank` in `ShowDistrict` function to select rows

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `district` FROM `ctable` WHERE state='$_POST[id]' AND bank='$bank' ";
```

but it doesn't works ...any way to do this ? ...Thanks in advance.

```
 class SelectList
 {
   protected $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DbConnect();
    }

    protected function DbConnect()
    {
        include "db_config.php";
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
        mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function ShowBank()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `bank` FROM `ctable` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $bank = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $bank .= '<option value="' . $row['bank'] . '">' . $row['bank'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $bank;
    }

    public function ShowState()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `state` FROM `ctable` WHERE bank='$_POST[id]'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $state = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $state .= '<option value="' . $row['state'] . '">' . $row['state'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $state;
    }


    public function ShowDistrict()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `district` FROM `ctable` WHERE state='$_POST[id]'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $district = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $district .= '<option value="' . $row['district'] . '">' . $row['district'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $district;
    }


          public function ShowBranch()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `bname` FROM `ctable` WHERE district='$_POST[id]'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $bname = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $bname .= '<option value="' . $row['bname'] . '">' . $row['bname'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $bname;
    }

}

$opt = new SelectList();
```

Comment: Uhm... `$bank = $this->ShowBank();`?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by deceze in the comments do this:

```
$bank = $this->showBank();
```

The `showBank()` function *returns* the `$bank` value. So you then pass the return value from the function to the variable `$bank` which can then be used.

`$this` lets you select the functions/variables inside you class.

Comment: @BharatJat ..That ís the example.

Answer (score 0):

in your code $bank is a string which is in while loop every time it concatenated with another string .

$bank contains a string like

```
 "<option value='bank1'>bank1</option><option value='bank2'>bank2</option>...";
```

so if you return that string it contains unnessary data

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `district` FROM `ctable` WHERE state='$_POST[id]' AND bank='$bank' ";
```

Comment: ohh ...i see ....i am talking about chained selects and third dropdown should be populated with help of first and second and not just first.Should i send the value of first and second dropdown to this php file to select proper District from Database in ShowDistrict function?